# How can I specify double quote string parameter in EL?

Tags: string, jsf, el, double-quotes

Recently, in a EL expression (using `#{}`), I have tried to pass a `String` parameter delimited by double quotes as first parameter of a java method using following code

```
<p:panel style="border:none;#{vC.traceUpdate("p:panel")}">
```

but this line is refused because double quote are use to limit `style` attibute and to limit `traceUpdate` parameter.

I have found an easy solution that consist to use simple quote instead of double quote to limit `style` attribute as show in following code

```
<p:panel style='border:none;#{vC.traceUpdate("p:panel")}'>
```

**But what do happening if first method's parameter type is `String` and next parameter's type is `char` as show in following code ?**

```
<p:panel style='border:none;#{vC.traceUpdate("p:panel",'X')}'>
```

In this extreme situation, it is not more possible to exchange quote and double quote.

I have tried followed code, but this is refused (highlight in red on Intellij-Idea) and crashes application !

```
<p:panel style="border:none;#{vC.traceUpdate(\"p:panel\",'X')}">
```

How can I solve this problem ?

This question is not a duplicate because  my question explicitely explain that problem is linked to double quotes ... and my question is how to pass a String AND a Char to a java method in EL expression

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that the best answer found is to use `'<string>'.charAt(0)` as proposed by BalusC in 
[[Passing a Character (vs passing String) to backing bean method in EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015322/passing-a-character-vs-passing-string-to-backing-bean-method-in-el][1])

```
<p:panel style="border:none;#{vC.traceUpdate('p:panel','X'.charAt(0))}">
```

but I have tried to use simple quote directly without using `charAt(0)` tips ... and this work correctly when parameter type is `char`.

Best solution

```
<p:panel style="border:none;#{vC.traceUpdate('p:panel','X')}">
```